# UITableView is adding empty rows and disabling scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Utilizing the method of populating a UITableView from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9430256/4138850), and setting the table to edit mode via:

```
tableView.editing = true;
```

And adding these methods:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{

}
```

I am seeing that a user can accidentally(or intentionally) double tab the ordering handle and insert an empty row. This will also kill the scrolling for the table view. Here is an image:

[image: iosbug]

Between "Logs" and "Settings" there is an empty row. I have looped through all rows on the table view via [the answers found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644635/ipad-iterate-over-every-cell-in-a-uitableview), and the empty rows are skipped over as if they don't exist.

**I was able to remove the empty rows via [tableView reload]** each time a row is moved, which unfortunately results in a kind of jarring snap. However, I haven't been able to re-enabled the scrolling. I am trying to avoid having to make the user close and redisplay the view.

Any one run across this issue and find a suitable work around?

**EDIT:**

**Row deletion is irrelevant** - this happens as a result of moving rows around

This is Xcode 6.1 on ios 8/7 - have also seen this Xcode 5.x -> ios 7/8.
We are targeting ipads, so not sure if this is an issue on iphone

Also, better description of how to reproduce:

- double tap cell and hold on second tap for a second
- drag cell up or down

[Posted on Apple forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1072940) and submitted bug to Apple. Here was the example project I submitted to them (in which I was able to reproduce said issue):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",
                        @"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",
                        @"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",
                        @"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",
                        @"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",
                        @"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five", nil];
    self.tableView.editing = true;
    [self.tableView setTableFooterView:[UIView new]];
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 20.0;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ScrollingDisplayCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if( cell == nil )
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCellNoPadding alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];   // MEMCHK: Autorelease so no ownership implications

        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier New" size:17.0];
        cell.textLabel.frame = cell.contentView.bounds;
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    NSString *stringToMove = self.tableData[sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.tableData removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.tableData insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}
```

And here is UITableViewCellNoPadding : UITableViewCell:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467288/center-align-text-in-uitableviewcell-problem
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.textLabel.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
}
```

NOTE: It was more difficult to reproduce here than in my own app

Comment: For `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`, do you have an implementation that changes the data to reflect the moved rows? `UITableView` can get very confused or upset when it asks its delegate/data source to change its data but the data doesn't reflect those changes.

Comment: Yes, I am updating the array with the new positions and am still seeing the same results

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified that users should not be able to delete rows, I added `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` to always return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone`. Without this implementation, `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` is returned by default.

With the implementation posted below, everything seems to behave well, and I've checked that all edits commit successfully to the table model.

I hope this helps!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.tableModel = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        [self addTableObject];
    }

    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    _tableView.editing = true;

}

- (void) addTableObject
{
    NSString *rowValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", _tableModel.count+1];
    [_tableModel addObject:rowValue];
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate methods

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [_tableModel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _tableModel.count;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    //Make change in data model
    id selectedValue = [_tableModel objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [_tableModel removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [_tableModel insertObject:selectedValue atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Comment: When you say "possible to delete", are you referring to the using the delete button? If so, I have actually disabled them in my application. The picture posted was with a different UITableView to ensure it wasn't my code causing the issue. I do not have that method, but I will implement it and see if it makes a difference

Comment: I was talking about there being no deletion code in the answer you linked to. So, I added the calls for updating the model and the table in tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Just to clarify - it is not possible for the user to delete any rows. The array is refreshed each time the view is entered. However, I will post results once I have a chance to test.

Comment: Okay, cool. I just added `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` to the answer to disable editing.

Comment: Ok, this is the same code I have and I am seeing the issue. I am assuming tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: is irrelevant? This does not happen as a result of hitting "delete". It happens when just moving the rows. Were you able to reproduce the listed issue before suggesting a fix?

Comment: I see, I wasn't sure if it was because you were not updating the model, because I did see some strange behavior when implementation is missing. And no, I was not able to reproduce the problem you described on the iPad.