# Add dynamic tableview to uitableview cell of static tableviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have static tableview controller and in that having one cell which having dynamic tableview....
I want to add cell at run time to dynamic tableview on 'add' button click... 
how to implement that delegate methods of both tableview ??

and how to add cell dynamically to that tableview???

Comment: tableviews either have static cells or dynamic cells, they can't have both

Comment: Have you check out SO for other answers like this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429618/adding-cells-programmatically-to-uitableview